# Vbscript - Creating an XML file and Adding Namespace

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm trying to use vbscript to create a xml file using the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products xmlns="http://www.myurl.com">
<product>
<url>http://www.link.com</url>
</product>
```

I was able to add all the elements for "products", "product" and "url", but the problem is that I don't know how to add the xmlns to the products element.

Here is my code:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("products")
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an attribute `xmlns` for the node:

```vbs
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("products")

Set xmlns = xmlDoc.createAttribute("xmlns")
xmlns.text = "http://www.myurl.com"
objRoot.setAttributeNode xmlns

xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot
```

Comment: That almost worked, problem is that it also added the AttributeNode to the second element. How can I prevent that?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <products xmlns="http://www.myurl.com">
     <product xmlns="">
     <url>http://www.link</url>
     </product>

Comment: @Zulake Why do you consider this a problem?